# How does tabular partitions affect end users?

Tags: ssas-tabular

I have a large SSAS Tabular model. I can do a full process on the server in about 10 minutes. That is not a problem. Problem is that end users who are using the model from either excel or Power BI are reporting sluggish performance.

Can partitioning the data help this and is there other solutions to speed up end users experiences?

Answer (score 0):

Partitions would only help you to reduce the processing time. Eg you could only reload "new" data on daily basis. They shouldn't affect the performance on client side.

I would recommend to focus on optimization on the DAX and model level.

Also when users connect with Excel as the client application there might be some performance issues even on optimized model. This is because Excel sends MDX queries to the Tabular and they are not really well optimized when using larger number of measures.